# Find duplicate rows in one column and print duplicated rows to a new dataframe table as a group using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My objective is to get the duplicated groups of column A and print/extract them into a new dataframe, ultimately to print each new dataframe into csv.

my current dataframe:

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 |

desired output:

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| C | 2 |
| C | 2 |

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| D | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the unique values of column A and can diplay the data with specific value of column A

Code:

```
[df[df['ColA']==i] for i in set(df.ColA.values)]
```

Output;

```
[  ColA  ColB
 0    A     2
 1    A     2
 2    A     3,
   ColA  ColB
 6    C     2
 7    C     2,
   ColA  ColB
 3    B     2
 4    B     3
 5    B     4,
    ColA  ColB
 8     D     2
 9     D     2
 10    D     3]
```

Comment: in set(df.ColA.values) function, how to write the variable ColA?

Comment: you can even write set(df['Column A'].values)

Answer (score 1):

```
g = df.groupby('column A')
dup_chk = df.loc[df['column A'].eq('A'), 'column B']
out = [g.get_group(x)[lambda x: x['column B'].isin(dup_chk)] for x in g.groups]
```

`out`(list of dataframes)

```
[  column A  column B
 0        A         2
 1        A         2
 2        A         3,
   column A  column B
 3        B         2
 4        B         3,
   column A  column B
 6        C         2
 7        C         2,
    column A  column B
 8         D         2
 9         D         2
 10        D         3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use `groupby` function to group each repeated elements in a row use `for` loop to loop through each group

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('column A')
for group in grouped_df:
    print(group)
```